Who was Blanca Subercaseaux, to whom Gabriela Mistral dedicated the poem Encargo a Blanca?
Many of Gabriela Mistral's poems are dedicated to specific persons. These are often authors who can be looked up on the Spanish Wikipedia, such as Emma Godoy, Max Daireaux, Francis de Miomandre, José Vasconcelos and Fryda Shultz de Mantovani. However, the poem Encargo a Blanca is not only dedicated to Blanca Subercaseaux; it also has her first name in the title.
Subercaseaux is "a Chilean family of French descent" but I could not find Blanca Subercaseaux on the Spanish Wikipedia or the French Wikipedia. Is there anything in the sources about Gabriela Mistral who Blanca Subercaseaux was and what sort of significance she had to Mistral?

Blanca Subercaseaux Errázuriz was a Chilean writer and artist, who also used the pseudonym "Carmen Valle" (at least one of Mistral's poems - "Bendiciones" - is dedicated to "Carmen Valle"). She was the sister of the artist Pedro Subercaseaux, who seems to be notable enough to merit his own wikipedia entry.
I find very little more information about her though, and even her dates of birth or death seem not to be known with any certainty. There is a glancing mention of her ("la progresista escritora y artista plástica Blanca Subercaseaux Errázuriz") in the biography of her son, Gabriel Valdés Subercaseaux who served as a minister and diplomat in Chile in the transition to democracy, following the removal of Pinochet. His biography also reveals that during his youth he met Gabriela Mistral "who came to live at his family's house through his mother's efforts".
Clearly Mistral and Subercaseaux were close friends. From a letter Mistral wrote to Francisco Dussuel1 in 1951, we learn the bare bones of the connection between the two women:

allá adentro nunca tuve entre mis numerosas amistades, sino una sola
alma con quien hablar: la preciosa criatura que se llama Blanca
Subercaseaux de Valdés. Nada más, nada más
there among my many friends, I only had one soul to talk to: the
precious creature called Blanca Subercaseaux de Valdés. Nothing more,
nothing more.

(the "de Valdés" refers to the surname of her husband, Horacio Valdés Ortúzar).

Tierra, indio, mujer: pensamiento social de Gabriela Mistral, L. Figueroa.

